# How to perform spatial interpolation using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgis-raster

I need to interpolate some point data and would like to use the ST_InvDistWeight4ma function.

As I am new to raster PostGIS, I would like to get some help about this.

Comment: @winwaed, thanks for your attention. I was stupid trying use this function on a old release of PostGIS... Thanks again!